# Basic CSS question about multiple instances of same object that should be treated differently

Tags: css

My website has a number of standard constructs in it, like tables and buttons and so forth. In some cases, I want one instance of a construct to be marked up one way and a different instance of the same construct to be marked up a different way. How do I write the CSS to accomplish that?

For instance, I have some checkboxes that I use for the Checkbox Hack that need to kept invisible or hidden offscreen and some other checkboxes that are real checkboxes that are used on forms. What's the best way to write the CSS so that I can distinguish between the two types of checkboxes and mark them each up differently?

Right now, I have the checkboxes used in the Checkbox Hack marked up like so:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
position: absolute;
top: -9999px;
left: -9999px;
}
```

This has the unfortunate side-effect of hiding my "real" checkboxes entirely.
I've learned my CSS in a slightly haphazard fashion so I never learned the standard approach(es) to this common situation. Could someone enlighten me on the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CSS classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).. for exmaple

```
input[type=checkbox].special {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

that way, only checkboxes that have `class="special"` will be affected.

Answer (score 0):

Yotam Omer is right, you should use classes. I do it this way:

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

then all you have to do is add the class "hide" to the checkboxes/other elements you want hidden.

```
<input type=checkbox class=hide>
```

Comment: Thank you, too, for an interesting variation that seems likely to be useful for many things.